# Remove service name from network aliases in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose1.yml

```
services:
  app1:
    (...)
    networks:
      - my_network

  db:
    (...)
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
    name: my_network
```

And docker-compose2.yml

```
services:
  app2:
    (...)
    networks:
      - my_network

  db:
    container_name: "db2"
    (...)
    networks:
      my_network:
        aliases:
          - replace_db_alias_please
networks:
  my_network:
    external: True
```

```
$ docker inspect db2
(...)
"Networks": {
  "my_network": {
    "Aliases": [
      "8c2da47d1e8e",
      "db",
      "replace_db_alias_please"
     ],
  }
}
```

The story is I need to put this services in the same network and network name **db** is ambigous. How to remove that alias from one service **without** changing service name?

Comment: Maybe you change the service name "db" to whatever you want ;)

Comment: Like I wrote in question, name must stay the same

Comment: @GregorWedlich: I'm pretty sure OP does no want to change it since the last four words of his question are **`without changing service name`**. Meanwhile, I'm not quite sure it is possible to fullfill this requirement in this case...

Comment: Yes sorry I did not read to the end, my mistake. As far as I know it is not possible to create more aliases but deleting them would be new to me.

Comment: @GregorWedlich ` it is not possible to create more aliases` => OP just has an example of that in his docker-compose file and it is perfectly possible.

Comment: I told you it was possible to add more... Sorry are my English skills to bad here?

[ALIASES](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty confident that the default alias cannot be removed. Depending on your specific usecase, you might try one of the following:

1. Adding aliases for both `db` services and not using the default one at all to avoid ambiguity.
2. If the `db` instances should be accessed only by the corresponding apps, you could create internal networks:

**docker-compose1.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:

  app1:
    networks:
      - my_network
      - internal

  db:
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  my_network:
    name: my_network
  internal:
    internal: true
```

**docker-compose2.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:

  app2:
    networks:
      - my_network
      - internal

  db:
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  my_network:
    external: true
  internal:
    internal: true
```